# Generate Swagger.json from a REST API endpoint class using Java

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have requirement to create an endpoint C that provides REST API Request Payload information of two other endpoints , I have made the two endpoints A and B Open API 3.0 compliant but I am not sure how I can parse the two endpoint class and generate the individual Swagger.json for each at runtime, since A and B endpoint class may change  but will remain Open API compliant, I have no control over that.

Comment: Can you please update your question to provide more detail?  As it stands, the question is entirely to broad for anyone to be able to provide a clear and targeted answer.  If you are just looking for a tool, then the [openapi generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#readme) is a pretty good tool for generating REST clients and servers from a valid schema.  It supports client generation for nearly 90 languages, server generation for nearly 50, and is updated constantly.